# How to replace empty variable with the wildcard char in WHERE clause in sql

Tags: php, mysql

Im passing two variables, via ajax - post method, into WHERE statement in query. Second variable $var2 is optional and it may or may not be sent. That means that second variable can be empty and query would not return any result.

```
SELECT table1.*
        FROM table1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id 
        WHERE table2.field1 = '".$var1."' AND table2.field2 = '".$var2."'
        ORDER BY table2.counter DESC
        LIMIT 10;
```

My first thought was to write if statement, something like

```
if(empty($var2)){
   query = ....WHERE table2.field1 = '".$var1."'...
}else{
   WHERE table2.field1 = '".$var1."' AND table2.field2 = '".$var2."'
}
```

Second thought was to assign * wildcard to $var2 if it is empty(this is not working).

Is there better way than if statement that could handle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: one way or another, you'd have to dynamically generate part of the script, so just do your "two versions of the where" option.\

Comment: When $var2 is empty, create different query without the "field2" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is correct;

```
if(empty($var2)){
   query = ....WHERE table2.field1 = '".$var1."'...
}else{
   WHERE table2.field1 = '".$var1."' AND table2.field2 = '".$var2."'
}
```

Add or take away from the query depending on the arguments. I do not think there is a wildcard like you want. Even if there was it doesn't matter, as omitting the second statement using an `if` has the same effect.

Comment: I was little worried about performance, but if its correct approach I'll go with it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like this:

```
$descriptiveName = !empty($var2) ? "AND table2.field2 = '$var2'" : "";

"SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id 
WHERE table2.field1 = '$var1'
$descriptiveName
ORDER BY table2.counter DESC
LIMIT 10"
```

That will set the `$descriptiveName` variable to a blank string (that will be ignored) if `$var2` is empty. It is also easy to add more than one condition this way, but if there are too many it is usually better to have two separate queries.